# Return-oriented programming: how to find a stack pivot

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, x86

I have a program with a heap overflow.  It contains some code that is not randomized (is not using ASLR).  I want to do a return-oriented programming exploit.  Since this is a heap overflow, the first thing I need to do is find a stack pivot, so I can get RSP pointing to a known memory address where my ROP program lives.

What are the state-of-the-art ways to find a stack pivot?  What instruction sequences should I look for?  Is there a list/database of instruction sequences that can be used as stack pivots?

Also, are there any defenses/mitigations I need to watch out for, or that it would help to be aware of?

---

For instance, I think I remember that `longjmp()` calls are a good place to find a stack pivot (e.g., a POP RSP ... RET sequence), assuming I control some value on the stack.  However, someone told me that some platforms now incorporate a mitigation to make exploiting `longjmp()` calls harder: they store setjmp buffers in encrypted form.  Is that right, and are there any ways to work around this mitigation, or should I give up on `longjmp()`s?

Another mitigation is that Windows 8's `VirtualProtect` function checks that it's being called with RSP set to something reasonable.  However, [others have documented how to bypass that mitigation](http://vulnfactory.org/blog/2011/09/21/defeating-windows-8-rop-mitigation/), so that's not a barrier -- and anyway, that's not focused on preventing the initial stack pivot.  My focus/interest in this question is on the initial stack pivot, not what you do thereafter.

Comment: If I am understanding it well, you call a '*stack pivot*' any kind of piece of code that is able to move the stack pointer to a place in memory that you control (the *heap* in your specific case). The point being to execute a ROP there. Am I right ?

Comment: @perror, yes, that's correct.

Comment: Well, to start with you'd have to find a POP ESP or MOV ESP somewhere.  :)

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding this question, you should be able to just use the Immunity Debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at mona by corelan

https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2011/07/14/mona-py-the-manual/

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  Mona looks very interesting.  Would you care to expand your answer to explain how it answers the question?  For instance, it appears that `mona stackpivot` outputs a file `rop_stackpivot.txt` containing a list of candidate stack pivots, though it's not clear what patterns it looks for or what instruction sequences it looks for.  Do you know?